# props value doesn't change in the input box

Tags: reactjs

I got the default value to be put in the input named "balance" from the parent component. However, the value cannot be changed to another value. Input values ​​with no other default values ​​can be changed very well.
I want to put the price value obtained from the parent component into the "balance" input as a default value. And since the value is editable, I want to change it to another value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';


class MortgageCalculator extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          balance: null,
          rate: null,
          term: 10,
          downpayment: null,
          output: null,
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    //  input element onchange event handler to update state
    onChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = parseFloat(target.value);
        const name = target.name;
    
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    }
    //  function to calculate monthly payments
    //  M = P [ I ( 1 + I )^N ] / [ ( 1 + I )^N – 1 ]
    calculate({ balance, rate, term, downpayment }) {
        if (rate === 0) {
        return;
        }
        const principal = balance - downpayment;
        const monthlyInterest = (rate * 0.01) / 12;
        const months = term * 12;
        const expression = (1 + monthlyInterest) ** months;
        const result = principal * ((monthlyInterest * expression) / (expression - 1));
    
        this.setState({
            output: ` $${parseFloat(result.toFixed(2))}`,
        });
    }


    render() {

        const price = this.props.price;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <p class="control-label">Sales Price</p>
                <input name="balance" className="tablet" type="number" placeholder={price}
                    value={ price } 
                    onChange={ this.onChange } />
                
                <p class="control-label">Down Payment</p>
                <input name="downpayment" className="tablet" type="number" placeholder="Down Payment ($)"
                    value={ this.state.downpayment } onChange={ this.onChange } />

                <p class="control-label">Interest Rate</p>
                <input name="rate" className="tablet" type="number" placeholder="Interest Rate (%)"
                    step="0.01" value={ this.state.rate } onChange={ this.onChange } />
                    
                <p class="control-label">Term</p>
                <select name="term" className="tablet" onChange={ this.onChange }>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                </select>
                
                <br/>
                <button name="submit" className="tablet" onClick={ () => this.calculate(this.state) }>
                    Calculate
                </button>
                <br/>
                <p id="output" className="output">Total Monthly Payment: { this.state.output }</p>
            </div>
            
        );
    }
} 

export default injectIntl(MortgageCalculator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a componentDidMount and set the state of balance to be the price. If i understand you correctly.

```js
  import React, { componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate } from "react";

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, balance: this.props.price });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // log the new state
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  // set the placeholder and value of the input to this.state.balance
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-framework-dewwi3?file=/src/cp.jsx:1400-1618